# 其れは... and 其の... Trying to restructure sentences using both words

Tags: syntax, particle-の, demonstratives

So I have this sentence:

> 其れはスーサンの鞄です

Can I restructure this sentence into:

> 其の鞄はスーサンのです

?

Comment: As an aside, それ and その are typically written in kana.

Comment: Do you mean スーザン (Susan)?

Comment: ^ 「スーさん」(「Sueさん」)やったりして・・・

Answer (score 4):

Yes, you can.

> 「それはスーサンの鞄{かばん}です。」

can be rephrased to:

・「その鞄はスーサン**の**です。」

・「その鞄はスーサン**のもの**です。」